# getTags return null - Phonegap, OneSignal

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, onesignal

I am using OneSignal for notifications. I need to get the tags from the server. If I call the function after registering again and sendtags again, then getTags() return newly sent tags. But it returns null if I call it without sending tags again. I think it is a problem with keeping the sessions.
Please somebody help me on this. Comment if you need more details.
Thank you

Comment: Are you fully uninstalling the app each time or just restarting your app? Are you testing on Android or iOS?

Comment: I'm testing on android and I only restart my app.

Comment: If I register for notification each time and sendtags,  then it returns the tags I passed. Otherwise it returns null.